# Differential Equation & Boundary-Value Problem: HELP Finding Arbitrary Constant Correctly?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I'm getting confused by a recurring theme involving solutions to boundary-value problems and the way the text is finding arbitrary constants:
$$
x^{2} y^{\prime \prime}-3 x y^{\prime}+3 y=24 x^{5}, \quad y(1)=0, \quad y(2)=0
$$
The solution is as follows:
The differential equation is a Cauchy-Euler DE. From the auxiliary equation
$$m(m-1)-3 m+3=(m-1)(m-3)=0$$ the general solution of the associated homogeneous equation is $$y=c_{1} x+c_{2} x^{3}$$

**In the application of conditions to find arbitrary constants below, I'm completely lost:**

- Applying $y(1)=0$ implies $c_{1}+c_{2}=0$ or $c_{1}=-c_{2}$.
- By choosing $c_{2}=-1$ we get $c_{1}=1$ and $y_{1}=x-x^{3}$.
- On the other hand, $y(2)=0$ applied to the general solution shows  $2 c_{1}+8 c_{2}=0$ or $c_{1}=-4 c_{2}$
- The choice $c_2 = -1$ now gives $c_1 = 4 $ and so $y_{2}(x)=4 x-x^{3}$

Q: This above 'choosing' of $c_1$ and $c_2$ is completely foreign to me. As I understand, $y_1$ should follow from the first half of the general solution ($c_1 x + c_2 x^3$). So $y_1 = x$ and $y_2=x^3$. The text however specifies $y_1 =x - x^3$ and $y_2 = 4x-x^3$.

So there's something I'm fundamentally misunderstanding regarding finding constants. For completeness I'll attach the rest of the problem below.

---

$$
W\left(y_{1}(x), y_{2}(x)\right)=\left|\begin{array}{ll}x-x^{3} & 4 x-x^{3} \\ 1-3 x^{2} & 4-3 x^{2}\end{array}\right|=6 x^{3}
$$

$$
G(x, t)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}\frac{\left(t-t^{3}\right)\left(4 x-x^{3}\right)}{6 t^{3}}, & 1 \leq t \leq x \\ \frac{\left(x-x^{3}\right)\left(4 t-t^{3}\right)}{6 t^{3}}, & x \leq t \leq 2\end{array}\right.
$$
Standard Form:
$$
y^{\prime \prime}-\frac{3}{x} y^{\prime}+\frac{3}{x^{2}} y=24 x^{3}
$$

$$
\begin{aligned} y_{p}(x) &=24 \int_{1}^{2} G(x, t) t^{3} d t \\ &=4\left(4 x-x^{3}\right) \int_{1}^{x}\left(t-t^{3}\right) d t+4\left(x-x^{3}\right) \int_{x}^{2}\left(4 t-t^{3}\right) d t \end{aligned}
$$
$$
y_{p}(x)=3 x^{5}-15 x^{3}+12 x
$$

Comment: Did you try to find the particular solution, since the general solution is sum of homogenous and particular one? The general solution should look like $y=c_1x^3+c_2x+3x^5$, then apply the boundary conditions.

Comment: How did you arrive at that general solution? The problem is to find the particular solution, then specify general solution as you say. But in this problem, I need the constants to identify equation 1 and 2 to use for Green Function to create particular solution.

Comment: What is the title of the book ?

Comment: @Aryadeva A First Course in Differential Equations with Modeling Applications by Zill

Comment: Thank you............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from [Differential Equation: Cauchy-Euler Boundary Value Problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3729860/differential-equation-cauchy-euler-boundary-value-problem)

You want to solve the equation for the Green function, $G_x(t)$ has to solve the normalized homogeneous DE with $\delta(t-x)$ as the right side,
$$
G_x''(t)-\frac3xG_x'(t)+\frac3{x^2}G_x(t)=\delta(t-x)
$$
with homogeneous boundary conditions. This means that for $t<x$ the solution is identical to a homogeneous solution that satisfies the left boundary condition, and for $t>x$ to a homogeneous solution that satisfies the right boundary condition. As everything is homogeneous, all such solutions differ by a factor, so select $y_1(t)=t-t^3$ and $y_2(t)=4t-t^3$ and
$$
G(x,t)=G_x(t)=\begin{cases}c_1(x)y_1(t)&\text{ for }t\le x,\\ c_2(x)y_2(t)&\text{ for }t> x.\end{cases}
$$
For continuity it is needed that $c_1(x)y_1(x)=c_2(x)y_2(x)$. Now add the unit jump condition for the derivative to find the usual $c_1(x)=\frac{y_2(x)}{W(x)}$ and $c_2(x)=\frac{y_1(x)}{W(x)}$.

The solution you computed automatically inherits the homogeneous boundary conditions from the Green's function, so that you do not have to determine additional coefficients.

Comment: To further simplify my confusion. From the homogenous solution I just specified above, my understanding of differential equations is that the first part ($y = c_1 x $) represents the $y_1$ and the second part ($y = c_2 x^3$) represents $y_2$. But that clearly must not always be the case.

What you described as "solutions differ by a factor, so select $y_{1}(t)=t-t^{3}$ and $y_{2}(t)=4 t-t^{3}$" is confusing me.

Comment: To isolate my issue, it's on how you specifically came about:
$$
y_{1}(t)=t-t^{3} \text { and } y_{2}(t)=4 t-t^{3}
$$
I get the homogeneous solution:
$$
y=c_{1} x+c_{2} x^{3}
$$
but fail to get to your correctly specified $y_1$ and $y_2$ from there. Here is the same issue with another problem:[Boundary-Value Problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3738654/differential-equations-simple-boundary-value-problem-w-solution-explanation)

Comment: But that you already solved, $y_1$ has to solve the left boundary condition $c_1+c_2=0$ and $y_2$ the right boundary condition, $2c_1+8c_2=0$. Any solution works, arbitrary factors cancel against the Wronski determinant.

Comment: $$
\begin{array}{c}c_{1}+c_{2}=0 \\ 2 c_{1}+8 c_{2}=0\end{array}
$$
The system, as you first pointed out, only has the trivial solution $c_{1}=c_{2}=0$. I get stuck there as Green's Function needs the two homogeneous equations to specify the particular solution. My text doesn't explain how to get past this.

Comment: In other words, the conditions imply $c_{1}=c_{2}=0$. So as I'm understanding the homogeneous equations is $y=0$

Comment: No, you get two separate functions with separate sets of coefficients. You only get one coefficient equation per function.

Comment: The larger point I'm getting at, after review, is that there's no general procedure for finding $y_1$ and $y_2$ for these problems?

Comment: The key here was understanding what it means to normalize about the condition. Thank you.

Comment: Do you know why Green's Function alone doesn't solve following initial-value problem? [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3746960/undamped-forced-motion-de-with-initial-conditions)

Appreciate it.

Comment: The solution is unique, both variation-of-constants and undetermined-coefficients give the same result if correctly applied.