# Undamped Forced Motion: Differential Equation with Initial Conditions (Problem + Solution)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm reading a math text on Differential Equations and it's introduced a Spring/Mass System: Driven Motion.

In an example involving Undamped Forced Motion the text asks to solve the initial-value problem:
$$
\frac{d^{2} x}{d t^{2}}+\omega^{2} x=F_{0} \sin \gamma t, \quad x(0)=0, \quad x^{\prime}(0)=0
$$
where $F_0$ is a constant and $\gamma \neq \omega$.

SOLUTION: The complementary function is $x_{c}(t)=c_{1} \cos \omega t+c_{2} \sin \omega t$. Assuming a particular solution $x_{p}(t)=A \cos \gamma t+B \sin \gamma t$:
$$
x_{p}^{\prime \prime}+\omega^{2} x_{p}=A\left(\omega^{2}-\gamma^{2}\right) \cos \gamma t+B\left(\omega^{2}-\gamma^{2}\right) \sin \gamma t=F_{0} \sin \gamma t
$$
Leading to
$$
x_{p}(t)=\frac{F_{0}}{\omega^{2}-\gamma^{2}} \sin \gamma t
$$
Applying conditions to
$$
x(t)=c_{1} \cos \omega t+c_{2} \sin \omega t+\frac{F_{0}}{\omega^{2}-\gamma^{2}} \sin \gamma t
$$
yields $c_{1}=0$ and $c_{2}=-\gamma F_{0} / \omega\left(\omega^{2}-\gamma^{2}\right)$. Thus final solution
$$
x(t)=\frac{F_{0}}{\omega\left(\omega^{2}-\gamma^{2}\right)}(-\gamma \sin \omega t+\omega \sin \gamma t), \quad \gamma \neq \omega
$$

**Q:** The conditions here are applied to the general solution. In the proceeding chapter covering Green's Function, this same type of problem in the form $y^{\prime \prime}+P(x) y^{\prime}+Q(x) y=f(x), \quad y\left(x_{0}\right)=0, y^{\prime}\left(x_{0}\right)=0$ was solved with the particular integral instead of the whole general solution. I'm confused as to the difference.

EDIT for clarity: Green's solution is as follows:
$$
y_{p}(x)=y_{1}(x) \int_{x_{0}}^{x} \frac{-y_{2}(t) f(t)}{W(t)} d t+y_{2}(x) \int_{x_{0}}^{x} \frac{y_{1}(t) f(t)}{W(t)} d t
$$

Comment: Have you verified that the end result is really different?

Comment: Either the Green's solves the equation with initial conditions or it doesn't. Are you claiming that is doesn't, or are you claiming that is does, but that the solution is different than the direct solution you obtained at first?

Comment: I was wrong about 'rest'. Green's function does solve a problem at rest like below but not above:
$$
y^{\prime \prime}+y=\sec ^{2} x, \quad y(\pi)=0, y^{\prime}(\pi)=0
$$
$$
y_{1}=\cos x, \quad y_{2}=\sin x
$$
$$
G(x, t)=\cos t \sin x-\cos x \sin t=\sin (x-t)
$$
and solution of IVP:
$$
\begin{aligned} y_{p}(x) &=\int_{\pi}^{x}(\cos t \sin x-\cos x \sin t) \sec ^{2} t d t \\ &=\sin x \int_{\pi}^{x} \sec t d t-\cos x \int_{\pi}^{x} \sec t \tan t d t \\ &=-\cos x-1+\sin x \ln |\sec x+\tan x| \end{aligned}
$$
But I have no idea why it doesn't apply above.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $F_0\sin(\gamma t)$ and not $\sec ^2$ ?

Comment: The problem in the comments is another initial-value problem that the book solves via Green's particular integral. My original question is why the same method doesn't apply to what seems like exactly the same type of problem.

Comment: Have you verified that the end result is really different?